# Do cats have a "right to roam" in the UK?

Tags: england-and-wales, liability

I've seen [numerous sources](https://www.iibinsurance.co.uk/company-news/can-cat-found-guilty-trespass), including [the RSPCA](https://www.rspca.org.uk/documents/1494939/7712578/CAT_adviceondeterringcats.pdf), making claims along the lines that cats in the UK have a "right to roam", are "free spirits", and therefore that cat owners cannot be held liable for their cat's actions that cause damage.  However, there appears to be no actual law that supports this.  For instance, the [Animals Act 1971](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/22) makes no mention of cats at all.  As far as I can tell, the law is incredibly vague on this issue.

Why, then, is there apparently widespread belief that cats have a right to roam?  Is there legal precedent establishing this?  If a cat owner were found liable in a county court for their cat having committed damages during their roaming, would there be any legal basis to challenge this decision?

Comment: If not, three follow-up question arise: 1. Would it be considered trespassing when my cat visits my neighbours garden 2. Would cats need to be leashed and walked like dogs in urban areas? 3. If my cat defecates on some other privately owned property, is that considered an offense (Think about some dog owned by a stranger jumping over your fence and dumping its load on your lawn)?

Comment: Usually, if something isn't explicitly prohibited then it's permitted

Comment: While your libinsurance.co.uk link does include the phrases "right to roam" and "free spirits", your RSPCA link doesn't. It says "Cats are protected by law and are free to roam", which isn't the same as claiming that cats have a legal right to roam.

Comment: (Of course, in the UK cats *can* be held legally liable for being just too cute and precious, with a maximum sentence of me trying to cuddle them for like 3 seconds before they squirm away.)

Comment: OI cat do you have a LOICENSE to roam?

Comment: I don't know about human law, but it's definitely true in **cat law**.

Comment: I suspect that far from any 'right to roam' cats have no right at all in British law…

The last time I looked was at least 40 years ago and what has changed since?

Back then, a car driver running over and slightly injuring a dog did, but one even killing a cat did not have a duty to report the incident…

Either way, how could the idea that a cat or any other animal might be either guilty of or somehow absolved from trespass not be ridiculous?

Comment: It appears that it has long been customary that cats aboard ships, who are kept in order to hold down the population of mice and rats, are not only allowed to roam freely, but are issued passports and other credentials certifying that they are free citizens.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The statement that cats cannot commit trespass is technically true, but is also a misreading of ss.4 and 4A of the Animals Act. Those sections replace a common-law doctrine called "cattle trespass", which was a specific tort (a civil wrong) concerning what happens when my cattle stray onto your land. Both old and new rules apply only to livestock, so not just cows but other kinds of farm animals as well - but *not* to dogs or cats. Horses are a special case (s.4A). Since cats are not livestock, they cannot be the subject of cattle trespass and are not covered by section 4.

Further, since they are animals, they cannot commit the tort of trespass at all. Animals themselves are not liable at law. As the *keeper* of cows, it would be *me* who was liable in a case of cattle trespass, not the cow. The point of s.4, and its predecessor in common law, is to make me liable for damage done to your property by my cows, regardless of whether I was negligent in the way I looked after them (it is a "strict liability"). The mere fact that they've strayed onto your land and done damage is enough.

Because cats are not cows, this particular rule does not apply. That does not mean that cats can't be the subject of other torts. In particular, cats could be involved in the tort of nuisance, which covers all sorts of potential scenarios - noise, smells, etc. This has typically happened when there are lots and lots of cats. And under the Animals Act, the keeper of *any* animal may be liable for damage that it does, including physical injury or damage to property.

Section 2 of the Act establishes a statutory distinction between whether I am *liable* for the damage, or *strictly liable*. In a scenario where I am strictly liable, you do not have to prove that I was negligent in my management of the animal. Broadly, that applies if the animal belongs to a dangerous species, or is unusually dangerous in itself. (There has been very complex litigation on this point which I am not discussing here.) If my cat is not a real vicious bastard of a cat, but just a regular cat, then I can still be liable for damage that he does: it's just not automatic.

Following Rachael Mulheron's *Principles of Tort Law* (CUP, 2nd ed., 2016), for an action in negligence there are several key points -

> Proving that D, the owner/keeper of an animal, owed C a duty of care, where C was injured by that animal, has been a straightforward task.
>
> The court must be satisfied that a reasonable person in the position of D, the keeper of the animal, would foresee a real risk of injury to C arising from D's particular acts or omissions in dealing with the animal. Otherwise, in the absence of that foreseeability, a reasonable D would have done nothing different in response to the risk posed by his animal.
>
> To fall below the standard of reasonable care as a keeper of an animal, D must have failed to do that which a reasonable keeper would have done (to supervise/fence/control, etc, the animal), or have done something which a reasonable keeper would not have done.
>
> In damage-by-animals cases, C must prove that, as in the usual negligence action, D's failure to supervise/handle/care for the animals caused C's injury on the balance of probabilities.

As in other negligence cases, there are various defences; if you hassled my cat and it scratched you, then that's your fault and not mine.

From the material quoted above, we can see that for a normal cat in the UK, where the owner is not doing anything unusual by letting it roam freely outdoors (as is typical for UK cats), it is going to be hard to meet the tests. Things may be different if D knows that C is allergic to cats, or that the cat has been eyeing up C's delicious prize goldfish, or has a bone to pick with D's own cat and is likely to attack her, or something. Most of the big cases under the Animals Act have involved animals who are more likely to cause damage, such as dogs, horses and cows; a cat is only legally different because (1) unlike for dogs, horses and cows, there are no special rules applying to cats, and (2) factually, most cats don't do much harm.

To that point, even if D is liable in the way described, C may not get very much out of them by way of damages. Defecation in C's garden is not pleasant, but is probably not worth a lot of money either.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144983/discussion-on-answer-by-alexg-do-cats-have-a-right-to-roam-in-the-uk); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: "Because cats are not cows" citation needed.

Answer (score 4):

> If a cat owner were found liable in a county court for their cat having committed damages during their roaming, would there be any legal basis to challenge this decision?

That begs the question of liability, doesn't it?

The bottom line is that cats are regarded both as fairly tame creatures which don't pose any general risk of unprovoked aggression or serious injury towards humans.

For this reason, they have not fallen under legal regimes designed to control dangerous animals (which are traditionally kept despite a danger because they have some kind of working role).

Instead cats are simply left to roam the environment in a natural manner. They have always performed a useful function mainly in controlling vermin.

Cats also do not generally pose a risk of causing serious "damage" to property, save where some arrangement is so fragile that any wild animal or adverse weather event might be prone to cause damage.

Because cats are relatively inert, there is no specific regime that holds owners liable for ordinary behaviours of cats.

However, unlike wild animals, domestic cats cannot be permanently captured or killed as they are regarded as the personal property of the owner (though the cats could well be seized temporarily or harassed if the purpose is to deter their future presence).

Ultimately, a landowner has no more right to be free of visitation from his neighbours' cats, as he has a right to be free from ordinary cooking smells, or the noise of children playing, or the runoff from a water source, or a variety of other things that are clearly imposed on him by the activity or arrangements of his neighbours, but which he has no right to control or hold his neighbour accountable for.

Comment: How about if the cat attacks the neighbour's cat, incurring vet costs?

Comment: @Jez, the fight would be regarded as between the cats themselves, and a natural peril the same as if the cat is hit by a car. If the owner opts to incur vet costs to maintain the cat, then they can do so, but nobody else is liable for those costs.

Comment: Serious damage to property isn't inconceivable: Cats do [sometimes have a habit of knocking things over](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/23833/9693), perhaps deliberately or perhaps trying to scent-mark.  If they did that with a source of ignition, they could do a lot of damage while behaving normally for the species.  The owner might know to avoid candelabra but the neighbour wouldn't (and my neighbour's cat sometimes wanders into my house if I leave the back door or a low window open for fresh air).  But it would take pretty bad luck

Comment: @ChrisH, the negligence would then be on the part of the person leaving these ignition sources lying around. A cat could step on a nuclear button, etc. Generally speaking, cats are anal retentive, and don't like to knock things over or attract attention, and they are most likely to do so only amongst unfamiliar objects.

Comment: @Steve that would be an interesting problem in its own right - it's normal to leave the room with a candle on the table in your own home, and even if not an electric lamp can also start a fire if smashed, a heater knocked over amd many other causes of damage .

Comment: @ChrisH, it's also normal for houses to go aflame. The bottom line in terms of the law, however, is that the householder is responsible for these things. Given interior furnishings today, the only *prudent* position is to have no naked flames indoors whatsoever - and certainly no unattended naked flames. No portable heater, placed reasonably on a firm floor and of a modern design, could be silently overturned by a cat.

Comment: @Steve no gas stoves? And who said anything about "silently"? But I'm getting further from the point that normal behaviour on all parts can lead to damage (a glass of red wine on a side table over a brand new cream carpet). And I was assuming an identifiably owned cat (collar perhaps), maybe even with a habit of entering other houses that had been raised with the owner.

Comment: @ChrisH, I wouldn't like to encounter the cat who knocks over gas stoves. As I say, a cat could step on a nuclear button - it's always possible to arrange things delicately. A landowner *isn't entitled* to arrange things so delicately then go with the begging bowl to his neighbour for damages, any more than he's entitled to make his boundary fence out of matchsticks then complain when the neighbour passing merely touches it and it collapses. The landowner has the right to make delicate arrangements, certainly, but only at his own risk and effort of maintenance. (1/2)

Comment: There is a strong analogy here with children. Children have something similar to the "right to roam", and at a certain age it's reasonable to expect that, unsupervised, they will roam around the neighbourhood without a great appreciation of property boundaries that adults will generally respect. It's incumbent on landowners to arrange matters on their property so as to be reasonably safe in those events. If they don't, then landowner risks loss and damage themselves, and they risk being penalised by the community if the arrangement of affairs on their land were found to be dangerous. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve I don't think I can contribute more here . I assumed you would realise that I meant your "no naked flames" implied "no gas stoves" and had nothing to do with cats. And we all know nuclear buttons aren't exactly things that get left lying around or even exist in a cat-able form, so you're clearly not unfamiliar with artificial examples . We could debate this all day but it wouldn't be a good idea

Comment: @ChrisH, there are actually considerable legal regulations around all aspects of gas stoves. I thought we were discussing scenarios in which cats might disturb the interior setting of the home in some dangerous or catastrophic way. My point is simply that landowners who make those settings, and then leave their doors and windows open, do so at their own risk. They are entitled to exclude or deter cats from entering, but the owners of cats are not liable when landowners fail to exclude or deter cats from entering, and some kind of damage then ensues.

Comment: @steve You seem to be making absolute statements about what people can and cannot do with their own property and how that affects liability, but of course, that's completely wrong. There is no guaranteed protection from liability, and there's no guarantee that a cat owner won't be found liable, partially or fully, for some destructive act by the cat.

Comment: @barbecue, I think it's settled law that there is no strict liability on the part of a cat owner, the cat owner cannot control the cat's whereabouts when it is outside, and there cannot be negligence by the cat owner in any circumstances where a cat is only behaving normally. The issue would not be about whether an act was destructive, but whether the cat owner was negligent somehow in connection with that destruction.

Comment: @steve the op never asked about strict liability, just liability in general.

Comment: @barbecue, I'm replying directly to you, not speaking to the OP's question. It's unclear on what basis you are believing that any liability can exist. Therefore to rebut some possible beliefs you may hold, I'm stating firstly that no general rule of strict liability exists for cat damage. So the mere fact that some cat causes damage does not implicate the owner. What remains is when the owner knows a particular cat he keeps to be dangerous in a way that isn't normal for cats, and he is effectively negligent for continuing to keep it at all (or for allowing it out the house). (1/2)

Comment: That said, I can't see that the OP's question is concerned with individual cats whose particular characteristics make them subject to control. He asks about cats in general, about their "rights to roam" and so on, so there is no reason to be looking with a magnifying glass about what the rules might be for cats with particular behaviour problems which are abnormal for cats as a whole. The law for cats in general, I'm afraid, is that unless the damage they cause is a result of abnormal personality, and unless the cat owner already knew this, then there is no liability. (2/2)

Comment: @steve In your last sentence you end up agreeing with me, so not sure what the point of all the disagreement is. I've never claimed any strict liability exists, cats are livestock, etc. If the law were as absolutely crystal clear and ineluctable as you maintain, there would literally be no need for any courts, attorneys, or judges to ever evaluate any cases. The entire reason we have courts is to evaluate INDIVIDUAL cases on their merits. Anyone who tells any other person that they are completely immune to all liability is always wrong.

Comment: @barbecue, perhaps we're just misunderstanding each other then. My answer replied to the OP in context. My comments above have replied to commentators in context. Nobody seems to be concerned with a dangerous cat which the owner knows to be dangerous. We're talking about typical cats with typical behaviour, and what liability exists for the owner in that general case - the answer is no liability. An owner of a cat behaving normally, is "completely immune to all liability" for anything the cat may do.

Comment: @steve I think we may be using different definitions of liability. To me, questions such as whether or not a cat is behaving normally, and whether or not the owner is negligent are the very questions at issue in determining liability. The assumption that everyone will always agree on what constitutes normal cat behavior, for example, seems unrealistic to me.

Comment: @barbecue, I agree, but I can only refer back to the context of the question, which is not about the threshold at which cat behaviour becomes abnormal, but about liability for "roaming" and damage that ensues meanwhile. In my view, the underlying question is about the existence of the hypothetical tort of cat trespass, and of a hypothetical strict liability for damage (such as fouling, marking, or the disturbance of an interior environment), it's not about liability for the escape of dangerous animals (which is the liability that most closely corresponds to your concern).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145078/discussion-between-barbecue-and-steve).